# Cannot RDP into Azure VM - User/Group Issue

Tags: azure, windows-server-2012, azure-virtual-machine

Frustrated with myself as I seem to have locked myself out of my Azure VM via RDP or FTP. When I try to login to the server via RDP I get an error message "The credentials are correct, but the host cannot log you on for another reason. "

I don't know how I caused this but I believe it has to do with users or groups somehow. I was struggling with setting up a user to be allowed FTP access to a specific folder, created a new group for the user and then set permission to the folder. Got him all setup but managed to lock myself out in the process.

Any idea of what to try before I call Azure support and pay their fee? (if they can even help)

Thanks, been a long day...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VM Access extension is designed to help you access an Azure virtual machine that you've been locked out of. You can use the Azure PowerShell module to configure the extension on your Azure VM.

`Get-AzureVM -ServiceName MyCloudService -Name MyVMName | Set-AzureVMAccessExtension -UserName MyUserName -Password MyPassw0rd! | Update-AzureVM;`

Comment: I will do some more research. Since I don't think this is a password issue will I be able to update groups or should I just add another admin user to get everything back in order via RDP?

Comment: You can configure the PowerShell Custom Script extension to deploy a PowerShell script to the virtual machine. It will be executed on the VM by the Azure VM guest agent. The script could create a new administrator account, sure. You can rename the "well known" admin account using the method I described above.

Comment: Thank you. All set but not a straightforward process since this has to be done on a Windows PC (had to pull one out and blow the dust off). 

In the end, the article that was most helpful in this situation was this one (the first command got me exactly what I needed: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-reset-password/

Comment: No need to pull out an old Windows PC, just create a new Windows Azure VM for that reason and throw it away after you have finished resetting your account.

Answer (score 0):

Try the tool first. It's really a life saver and very simple to use.

**Microsoft Azure IaaS (Windows) diagnostics package**

https://home.diagnostics.support.microsoft.com/SelfHelp?knowledgebaseArticleFilter=2976864

Additional info on this blog post:

**Troubleshoot Remote Desktop connections to a Windows-based Azure Virtual Machine**

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-troubleshoot-remote-desktop-connections/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure Resource Management, instead of Azure Service Management, you will need different set of commands:

See available machines for subscription (assuming you have logged in already):

```
Get-AzureRMVM | select Name, ResourceGroupName
```

Select machine you need to work on:

```
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -Name '<VM_NAME>' -ResourceGroupName '<RG_NAME>'
```

Create new credentials:

```
$cred=Get-Credential
```

Set credentials on VM:

```
Set-AzureRmVMAccessExtension -VMName '<VM_NAME>' -ResourceGroupName '<RG_NAME>' -UserName $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Username -Password $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password -Name '<EX_NAME>'
```

Update VM:

```
Update-AzureRmVM -VM $vm
```